# linking live excel spreadsheet to power point 2003

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I need to set up quite a lot of slides on powerpoint 2003 which link to excel data. This data refreshes each month. I have linked it but as soon I double click on the chart it does not remember that it is linked and power point opens with another excel sheet (the one that is attached to power point). Does anyone know how to link it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't linked the spreadsheet but have instead embedded it.

To link:

Go to Excel and open or create the spreadsheet you want to link to.
You must save it at least one time.

Select the content you want to include in PPT, rightclick and choose Copy or do Edit / Copy.  Ctrl+C SHOULD work but is unreliable in some versions.

Switch to PPT, choose Edit, Paste Special, put a check next to LINK and make sure that Excel Worksheet Object or Excel Chart Object is selected in the list box to the right.

Click OK.

NOW you have a linked spreadsheet or chart.